# Draw rectangle using boundingBox

Tags: ios, swift, vision

Through VNRecognizeTextRequest I am getting the following coordinates from a specific boundingBox: (0.21611927830895714, 0.4163079471243136, 0.017705895179925962, 0.1368724813140948).

My question is how can I draw a rectangle on top of a UIImageView using these boundingBox coordinates?

Answer (score 3):

To convert from normalized to image coordinates you can use the following

```
let rectInImage = VNImageRectForNormalizedRect(boundingBox, image.size.width, image.size.height)
```

From there you can use a UIBezierPath to draw the path:

```
func drawRect(_ rect: CGRect, layer: CALayer) {
    let center = CGPoint(x: rect.midX, y: rect.midY)
    let path: UIBezierPath = UIBezierPath(rect: rect)

    let rectShape: CAShapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    rectShape.path = path.cgPath
    rectShape.position = center
    rectShape.bounds = rect

    rectShape.strokeColor = UIColor.green.cgColor
    rectShape.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
    rectShape.lineWidth = 1.0

    layer.addSublayer(rectShape)
}
```